# How can I schedule notification according to user input?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-notifications

I've tried a bunch of things in order to notification worked well, but nothing is working properly... This is my NotificationPublisher class

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,CreateNewPvpFragment.class);
        long[] pattern = {0,300,0};
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,01234,intent,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle("PVP")
                .setContentText("Verify your PVP")
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(01234,mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And here my NotificationReceiver class:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context,NotificationPublisher.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

And finally my method in my Fragment

```
public void addReminder (int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,mYear);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,mMonth);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,mDay);

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,15);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        c.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

        int alarmId = 001;
        alarmId = Integer.parseInt(mDay+""+mMonth+"");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),alarmId,intent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

This method its receiving values from the Datepicker dialog, according to user input.
Before, it was working only with the current day, but now neither with that

Comment: Just a note from the docs of set method: If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, that previous alarm will first be canceled.

Comment: So, how can I solve this? The classes are right?